# Stop ms Access VBA opening Excel File Read-only

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, com

I have an Access file which uses tables linked to an Excel file, which in itself has other links that need refreshing.
(Please please don't question the logic of that, it is a workaround for some knotty problems and genuinely the only way of doing it for now because access can't use .odc connections)
I have a button in an access form that should update the data.
However when the `button_onclick` sub opens Excel it always opens it as read-only, and therefore breaks when trying to save the file. How do I prevent this?

I have already tried `AppExcel.AlertBeforeOverwrite = False` and entering the `ReadOnly` parameter as false on `Workbook.Open` but it still happens.

Code is as follows;

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click()
Dim AppExcel As Excel.Application
Dim wbConn As Excel.Workbook

Set AppExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
AppExcel.Visible = True
Set wbConn = AppExcel.Workbooks.Open("Z:\Company Records\System Files\Connection Data.xlsx", True, False) 'Note that last parameter, Readonly = False
With wbConn
    .RefreshAll
    'Debug.Assert False
    AppExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False 'This doesn't work
    .Save 'BREAKS HERE - message boxes in Excel because the file is Read-only
    .Close
End With
Set wbConn = Nothing
Set AppExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using `AppExcel.Workbooks.Add` instead? It creates a new workbook using the workbook that you would normally be opening. This however assumes you do not need the filename to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True`

```
Set wbConn = AppExcel.Workbooks.Open("YourFilePath", True, False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
```

If it does not work try directly:

```
Set wbConn = AppExcel.Workbooks.Open("YourFilePath", True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
```

Another additional solution would be to always `.SaveAs` the file instead of using `.Save` for which you could change the name of your file or use `ConflictResolution` to overwrite the existing file

```
.SaveAs Filename:="YourFilePath", ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
```

I suggest you add `AppExcel.DisplayAlerts = False` to the beginning of your code if you want to avoid the prompt messages that overwriting the file could cause